# Elasticsearch aggregation for Group By then get Avg of field for Max date

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-dsl

I'm trying to build a query in Elasticsearch which will do: 
a) Group By a field (that is `department_name`) 
b) Get the documents with the max date(that is `record_date`) 
c) Calculate the average of the field of the remaining documents(that is `risk_index_value`).

I've managed to build the query below in case my description isn't that helpful:

```
{
   "size":0,
       "query" : {
        "match": {
          "record_date": "2021-04-08"
        }
    },
   "aggs":{
      "assets":{
         "terms":{
            "field":"department_name",
            "size":10000
         },
         "aggs":{
            "risk_avg":{
               "avg":{
                  "field":"risk_index_value"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

This query does exactly what I want to in terms of business logic, but I need somehow to always get the max date without giving a value for it. Is there a way to do that? I need to do this with the REST High Level Elastic Client, but even the raw query would be really helpful. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I will add some document examples so that my request makes more sense.

So imagine we have 11 documents:

```
department_name: A
risk_index_value: 10
record_date: 2021-04-28

department_name: A
risk_index_value: 30
record_date: 2021-04-28

department_name: A
risk_index_value: 20
record_date: 2021-04-28

department_name: A
risk_index_value: 100
record_date: 2021-04-20

department_name: A
risk_index_value: 80
record_date: 2021-04-20

department_name: B
risk_index_value: 240
record_date: 2021-04-28

department_name: B
risk_index_value: 220
record_date: 2021-04-28

department_name: B
risk_index_value: 200
record_date: 2021-04-28

department_name: B
risk_index_value: 100
record_date: 2021-04-20

department_name: B
risk_index_value: 90
record_date: 2021-04-20

department_name: C
risk_index_value: 45
record_date: 2021-04-28
```

So on the data below, the query I need would return something like:

```
department: A
risk_index_avg: 30
record_date: 2021-04-28

department: B
risk_index_avg: 220
record_date: 2021-04-28

department: C
risk_index_avg: 45
record_date: 2021-04-28
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: you want to get the document having max `record_date` ?

Comment: i want to get the average of 'risk_index_value' from each group of documents(groups divided according to deparment_name value) with max date. was that any clear?

Comment: what do you mean by **(groups divided according to deparment_name value) with max date.**? I am not able to understand **max date** here

Comment: I added some example data, hope that will make it clear. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understood from your question, **you want the average risk index of the latest record date in each department.**

###### There is way to find the max value using the terms aggregation. i.e;

1. Use terms aggregation on required field
2. Sort the term keys in descending order `"order": { "_key": "desc" }`
3. Get only one top value by saying `size = 1`. ***(which will be the max value)***

```
"aggs": {
   "maxKey": {
      "terms": {
         "field": "<field whose max is required>",
         "size": 1,
         "order": {
            "_key": "desc"
          }
       }
   }
}
```

I think, Below is the query you are looking for.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "EachDepartment": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "department_name",
        "size": 1000
      },
      "aggs": {
        "MaxRecordDate": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "record_date",
            "size": 1,
            "order": {
              "_key": "desc"
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "AvgOfRiskIndex": {
              "avg": {
                "field": "risk_index_value"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And I tried to execute this with the sample data provided by you and got the below response.

```
{
  "aggregations" : {
    "EachDepartment" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "A",
          "doc_count" : 5,
          "MaxRecordDate" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 2,
            "buckets" : [
              {
                "key" : 1619568000000,
                "key_as_string" : "2021-04-28 00:00:00",
                "doc_count" : 3,
                "AvgOfRiskIndex" : {
                  "value" : 20.0
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "B",
          "doc_count" : 5,
          "MaxRecordDate" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 2,
            "buckets" : [
              {
                "key" : 1619568000000,
                "key_as_string" : "2021-04-28 00:00:00",
                "doc_count" : 3,
                "AvgOfRiskIndex" : {
                  "value" : 220.0
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "C",
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "MaxRecordDate" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [
              {
                "key" : 1619568000000,
                "key_as_string" : "2021-04-28 00:00:00",
                "doc_count" : 1,
                "AvgOfRiskIndex" : {
                  "value" : 45.0
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I hope this answered your question.

**EDIT: Added RestHighLevelClient code to create the aggregation**

```
AggregationBuilder getAggsBuilder() {
    AggregationBuilder departmentAggs = AggregationBuilders.terms("eachDepartments")
                .field("department_name")
                .size(1000);
    AggregationBuilder maxRecordDateAgg = AggregationBuilders.terms("maxRecordDate")
                .field("record_date")
                .size(1)
                .order(BucketOrder.key(false));
    AggregationBuilder avgRiskIndexAgg = AggregationBuilders.avg("avgRiskIndex")
                .field("risk_index_value");

// add avgRiskIndexAgg to maxRecordDate
    maxRecordDateAgg.subAggregation(avgRiskIndexAgg);

//add maxRecordDate to departmentAggs
    departmentAggs.subAggregation(maxRecordDateAgg);
    return departmentAggs;
}
```

Comment: The requirements chenged a bit, but still through your aggregation I found another answer I've been searching so thank you very much!